# Enable Loki Network Node for public access and also to view /get_info using loki.conf file

Tags: loki, service-node, public-node

I setup a loki network node and have it fully synced to the network. I want to be able to enable public access and also to view the /get_info data when I goto my node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of lokid 8.1.3 the preferred setting is now:

```
rpc-public=0.0.0.0:22023
```

which replaces the older:

```
rpc-bind-ip=0.0.0.0
rpc-bind-port=22023
restricted-rpc=true
confirm-external-bind=true
```

quartet and also leaves an unrestricted localhost:22023 listener so that you can still invoke restricted rpc commands locally.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new file in your .loki folder:

```
vi ~/.loki/loki.conf
```

And put in the following:

```
no-igd=true
rpc-bind-ip=0.0.0.0
#rpc-bind-port=99999
restricted-rpc=false
confirm-external-bind=true
```

Then restart your loki.

You can access your /get_info from your ip: http://127.0.0.1:22023/get_info

Comment: As Loki is a fork of Monero (and I doubt they've changed these features), `no-igd=true` is not needed (as that just switches off UPnP port mapping, which you may actually want if connecting remotely), and `restricted-rpc=false` you should point is also not needed, and that running unrestricted leaks some privacy info.